# Sequelize - setting property of an instance does nothing?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I've used the standard instance syntax before without issue, but in this part of my code I can't seem to update an instance I've fetched from the database.

```
...
const instance = await db.models.Users.findOne({where: {profileName: foundChange.profileName}});
instance.profileName = webUser.username;
await instance.save()
console.log(`Profilename: ${instance.profileName}`);
```

Console returns the value it was before setting.
I've also tried `instance.set(key, value)` which similarly has no effects. Am I missing something?

I've found that directly addressing instance.dataValues will change it, but that seems to go against the Sequelize documentation. Will this way update properly?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because I'm trying to update the primary key actually! Probably a sign I should do some remodelling...